# Redirect to another domain doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess

why this redirect does not work.

From the domain https://blog.all-of-knb.pl/ at https://kuroko-no-basuke.make4u.eu/.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.blog.all-of-knb\.pl$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/kuroko-no-basuke\.make4u\.eu\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.blog.all-of-knb\.pl$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/kuroko-no-basuke\.make4u\.eu\/" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.all-of-knb\.pl$
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://kuroko-no-basuke.make4u.eu/ [R=301,L]
```

You `%{HTTP_HOST}` regex matching is no good. `.` matches any character whereas `\.` matches only dot character.